# Trying to use jQuery's .addClass method with navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, addclass

i have a Nav wherein i'm attempting to use jQuery's addClass method to set the link color of the last clicked link. problem is then i have to use removeClass on all other links in the Nav. that's what i'm having trouble with.

I have written the code in a naive way, but know this is not good programming. below is the code with style sheet ref.

```
jQuery('#shop-nav').click(function(){
    jQuery("#shop-nav").addClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#art-nav").removeClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#obj-nav").removeClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#acc-nav").removeClass("clicked");
});

jQuery('#art-nav').click(function(){
    jQuery("#art-nav").addClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#shop-nav").removeClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#obj-nav").removeClass("clicked");
    jQuery("#acc-nav").removeClass("clicked");
});
```

etc. etc!

the HTML is

```
<div id="nav-cell-1" class="grid f-cell nav-cell">
<ul id="main-nav" class="nav clearfix">
    <li><a href="#" id="shop-nav">Shop</a>
        <ul id="shop-cats">
            <li><a href="#" id="art-nav">Art</a></li>
            <li>&#8226;</li>
            <li><a href="#" id="obj-nav">Objects</a></li>
            <li>&#8226;</li>
            <li><a href="#" id="acc-nav">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a:link, a:visited {color:#cfb199;text-decoration:none} /* official this color:#9d9fa1; work color: #222*/
a:active, a:hover {color:#9d9fa1;text-decoration:none} /* old color:#9d9fa1; */ /* official color:#cfb199; work color: #f00*/
a:link.clicked, a:visited.clicked {color:green;text-decoration:underline}
```

a demo site is here:
http://www.tomcarden.net/birdycitynav/partial-nav-demo.html

I did solve part of the problem by using the `this` reference, but this do not include the `.removeClass` part.

```
jQuery('#shop-cats>li>a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify that the HTML hierarchy above is correct, and that clicking on the outer `<li>` should also have this click handler called?  Most answers seem to be ignoring the outer list.

Answer (score 3):

Or this one works more like your site:

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
    $('.nav a').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

test it here:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/mjYq3/18/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to toggle the class:

```
var navs = jQuery('#shop-nav,#art-nav, #obj-nav, #acc-nav');
navs.click(function(){
    navs.removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Comment: this doesn't scale if you add links you have to add to that array.  Not very DRY or unobtrusive

Comment: If the number of tabs/links is not fixed then yes this is not the apt way.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
jQuery('#shop-cats>li>a').click(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.parent().children('a').removeClass('clicked');
    $this.addClass("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove all the clicked classes then add it back to just the one that was clicked.

```
jQuery('#shop-cats>li>a').click(function(){
  jQuery('#shop-cats>li>a').removeClass("clicked")
  jQuery(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work:

```
$('#main-nav a').click(function() {
    $('#main-nav a').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

On the basis that you apparently want to do this for all links that are descendents of `#main-nav`, and not just those that are in the inner `<ul>` list.